# How to write Division operation in WebApi2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapi2

In c# we have try & catch block we know how to avoid `"Attempted to divide by zero` But in WebAPi2.0 how can i Restricts user not Enter **1/0  Or -1/0**

```
 public IHttpActionResult div(int a, int b)
        {
            return Ok(a / b);
        }
```

Comment: The exakt same way. 
Web Api is only one way of handle communication. 
The C# logic remains the same. 
Create a method/class that handles the calculation which you call from your controller.

Comment: Could u plz Reffere any sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You handle this the exact same way.
Web Api is only one way of handle communication. The C# logic remains the same.

This is an example of how to do it using DI

```
public class DivisionController: ApiController
{
    private readonly ICalcService _calcService;

    public DivisionController(ICalcService calcService)
    {
        _calcService = calcService;
    }

    [HttpGet]     
    public IHttpActionResult div(int a, int b)
    {
        return Ok(_calcService.Divide(a,b));
    }
}


public class CalcService: ICalcService
{
    public decimal Divide(int a, int b)
    {
        if(b == 0)
        {
            //handle what to do if it's zero division, perhaps throw exception
            return 0;
        }

        return a / b;
    }
}
```